# Why this Shanks Transformation of Lebniez Series of PI taking to much time?

Tags: python, pi

So i saw Lebniez Series for Pi which is very slowly converging . So I applied Shanks Transformation. Then i kept on recursively Applying the Shanks transform . Here is my code:-

```
def lebniez(n):
    pi = 0
    n = n + 1
    for i in range(1,n):
        if(i % 2 == 1):
            pi -= 1 / (2*i - 1)
        else:
            pi += 1/(2*i - 1)
    pi = abs(4 * pi)
    return pi

def accelrate(n,depth):
    if depth == 1:
        a = lebniez(n + 1)
        b = lebniez(n)
        c = lebniez(n-1)
        return (a*c - b*b)/(a + c - 2*b) 
    a = accelrate(n + 1,depth - 1)
    b = accelrate(n,depth - 1)
    c = accelrate(n-1,depth - 1)
    return (a*c - b*b)/(a + c - 2*b)
```

Please tell why this is so consuming so much Time. Due to recursion I guess. Can this be improved ?

Comment: Define "too much time" and what you expect it to take. Recursion in itself is a performance hog. You can convert `accelerate()` to a non-recursive one. This may also allow you to put some parallelism in your code. Note that recursion is also prone to "screwing" things up depending on the recursion level (here `depth`) you want to reach. Python also has its limit. You can check your max recursion level by calling `sys.getrecursionlimit()` from the `sys` module. You can also set it accordingly (to a lower than the max value) if you want to put some constraints.

Comment: Yes i am confused how can i optimise recursion. Sorry for too much error as i am just of 13 years